How to Properly Set Up a Node.js Application with Docker Without Storing node_modules Locally?
I'm new to Docker and Node.js and I'm trying to set up a Node.js application using Docker. I prefer using Docker over nvm to manage my Node.js version. Here's the issue I'm facing:
Steps I've Taken

Initial Dockerfile Setup:

Created a Dockerfile in my project directory with the following content:
Dockerfile FROM node:14 USER node WORKDIR /app
Built and ran the container, mapping the volume with -v ${PWD}:/app.
Opened a shell on the container using docker exec.
Ran npm init --yes && npm i mongoose, which created node_modules both in the container and in my local repository.


Modified Dockerfile:

Updated the Dockerfile to perform npm install, expose ports, and add other necessary commands as I proceeded. This setup worked fine, but it left a node_modules folder in my local directory.



Alternative Approach

Instead of using the shell to execute npm init and npm install, I wrote a package.json file directly.
Created a standard Dockerfile with FROM, WORKDIR, COPY, and EXPOSE. I didn't include the CMD as there's no JS file to run yet.
This raised an issue: after running the container, the node_modules folder wasn't created in the directory. I suspect this is due to mounting the volume with -v ${PWD}:/app.

Question
How can I properly set up my Node.js application with Docker so that the node_modules folder is created and used inside the container without it being stored locally?
Thank you for your help!
What I Tried:

Initial Dockerfile Setup:

Created a basic Dockerfile with the following content:
FROM node:14
USER node
WORKDIR /app


Built and ran the container using:
docker build -t my-node-app .
docker run -v ${PWD}:/app -it my-node-app


Opened a shell in the running container:
docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/sh


Ran:
npm init --yes && npm i mongoose

This created a node_modules folder both in the container and in my local directory.


Modified Dockerfile:

Updated the Dockerfile to:
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]


Rebuilt and ran the container. This setup worked, but the node_modules folder was still present in my local directory due to the volume mapping.


Alternative Approach:

Wrote a package.json file directly with the required dependencies.
Created a standard Dockerfile:
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]


Ran the container with:
docker build -t my-node-app .
docker run -v ${PWD}:/app -it my-node-app


This time, the node_modules folder was not created in my local directory, but it also wasn't available in the container.



What I Expected:
I expected the node_modules folder to be created and used inside the Docker container without being present in my local directory. This way, I can manage dependencies within the container, keeping my local workspace clean. I am looking for a solution to achieve this.

You're volume mapping your entire /app folder but somehow you want only the source files mapped between the host and the container, but you want the node_modules folder only in the container -- even though it's in the volume-mounted /app folder, right?  I think the solution is to put all your source into a /app/src folder and only volume mount that folder, not the entire /app folder.

There is trade off between mounting your volume and having the node_modules in your folder and not mounting and not having it. when you mount you will be able to check your changes directly or just by restarting your container  but you will have to have the node_modules also presend in your local due to volume bind (good for development) but if you dont mount the volume you will have ease of not having the heavily populated node modules folder in your local but the trade off is you will have to rebuild the container for every change you make to your app in local

A common way to do this is to map an anonymous volume to the node_modules directory (see this). I've only been able to make that work when the container runs as root though. When running as another user, it fails because the node_modules directory is owned by root and I can't find a way to change the ownership.

You're launching your container with:
docker run -v ${PWD}:/app -it my-node-app

This means that you're replacing the entire contents of the /app folder in the container with what appears in your current working directory on the host.
This will not be conducive to having just the source files mapped (e.g. /app/app.js) but somehow not mapping the node_modules folder (i.e.: /app/node_modules), because the node_modules folder is within the folder that you have mounted to the host.
Restructure your folders
Instead, I suggest restructuring your folders so that the source files you want to map between host and container are their own folder, and then mount only that source folder.
This should be fine because modifying package.json will require a new npm install within the container whereas source .js file changes can be picked up on the fly.  Especially if you want to use nodemon to automatically pick up changes.
Old structure:
│   app.js
│   package-lock.json
│   package.json
│
└───node_modules
    │   .package-lock.json

New structure:
│   package-lock.json
│   package.json
│
├───node_modules
│       .package-lock.json
│
└───src
        app.js

Launch like this:
docker run -v ${PWD}/src:/app/src -it my-node-app

Of course, you will have to change your main property in your package.json to reflect the new location of the source files.  For example:
From:
"main": "app.js"

To:
"main": "src/app.js"


You are right, node_modules should not be stored just like in other languages:

/bin (dlls) for c#
/target (jars) java

Your approach #3 is the correct, just don't mount the volume.
Clean as possible
Your Dockerfile could be simple like this
FROM node:22
WORKDIR /opt/
COPY . /opt/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["npm","run","start"]

Don't mount nothing
You can do whatever you need on your localhost but for real nodejs applications on servers, your container should be portable and disposable, so the disk should not be used as datasource (json, xml, data) or file repository (csv, reports, pdfs, logs, etc).

If you need to store files, I suggest you to use some specialized service like aws s3, azure blob, gcp cloud storage, etc.
For data you have a lot of engines (mysql, postgres, etc).
For logs: aws cloud watch, gcp (Cloud Logging, Stackdriver), etc

References

https://github.com/jrichardsz/nodejs-express-snippets/tree/master/docker

